# Exception handling in amazon S3 SDK for PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I recently migrated from age old amazon AWS SDK (v1.6.2) for PHP to the latest one. One thing I completely missed was Exception handling.

My first code.

```
$result = $this->S3Client->putObject($options);
if (!empty($result)) {
    return !0;
}
```

But if upload fails, then it will throw an exception which will crash my PHP. So, I added exception handling next.

```
try {
    $result = $this->S3Client->putObject($options);
    return !0;
} catch(Exception $e) {
    log_message($e->message);
    return !1;
}
```

However, it seems that `$e->message` is protected.

**Question:** How can I get the error so that I can root cause what happened with the upload, once I move to production environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
log_message($e->getMessage());
```

More info [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/quick-start.html#detecting-and-handling-errors) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Exception.html#_getMessage).